# How i Can Focus IFRAME In FireFox?

Tags: javascript

i cannot focus IFRAME In FireFox , But i Can Focus it on IE as Follow:

**frames["MyFrameID"].focus();**

i have trying many solutions but all not working , Can Any One Help Me??

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
document.getElementById('MyFrameID').focus();
```

---

However, the `focus()` method is not defined for IFRAME elmements: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-50708718

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.getElementById("MyFrameID").contentWindow.focus();
```

Edit: I don't think you an access a particular frame in Firefox using the id in the frames collection.

Answer (score 0):

The `focus()` method is defined for IFRAME elements.

Have a look here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

It is listed in html tags which support it.